# iPad iOS7 Orientation Problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios7, rotation

I have an app that changes the view when the orientation changes using: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]. On the iPhone, it works but on the iPad, it gives me landscape instead of portrait and portrait instead of landscape.

1. When I call the **getRelevantFrame** method outside of the *UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification*, it will return the correct frame.
2. It will return the opposite frame (if landscape, will return portrait and vice versa) when responding to the notification.
3. Both the versions (iPod/iPhone + iPad) uses the same code but this only breaks on the iPad version

Here is the code I used to calculate the relevant frame:
EDIT: Used rob5408's advice. Changed to use UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM().

```
+ (CGRect)getRelevantFrame {
    //Get orientation
    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

   if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) { //iPhone/iPod
        if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
            return [self frameiPhoneLandscape];
        }
        else {
            return [self frameiPhonePortrait];
        }
    } else if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) { //iPad
        if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
            NSLog(@"iPad Landscape");
            return [self frameiPadLandscape];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"iPad Portrait");

            return [self frameiPadPortrait];
        }
    }

    return CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Here is the notification I used:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didRotate:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Here is the code I used to read the orientation change:

```
- (void) didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Parent: %@", self.parentController);
    if(self.parentController) {
        [self setFrame:[TASFrames getRelevantFrame]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Do yourself a solid and use `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad` instead of using view bounds. That probably won't fix it, but it is going to save you problems in the future.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will definitely use that from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I transferred the code to a new project. And now it works as it's supposed to. No idea as to why this happens. Code didn't change.